# Apache Web server to Tomcat proxy redirection settings result in corrupted response issue

Tags: angularjs, java-8, tomcat7, apache2.4

When we access the server directly through port 8080 (without proxy settings) we are not getting the randomly corrupted response and when we configured Apache and Tomcat with proxy settings using mod-proxy-ajp and mod-proxy to run on port 80 instead of 8080 we are getting the randomly corrupted response.

We tried using http instead of ajp but it didn't worked.
We also have Websocket in our application

My server configuration :

```
Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
Apache Web Server/2.4.10
Java version 1.8.0_161
```

Following is my setting of apache web server to tomcat redirection :

File: /etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname

    Redirect / https://domainname/

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domainname

    Redirect / https://domainname/myapp/login.html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /myapp/ ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/ retry=0 timeout=385

    ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/
    ProxyPass /myapp/busy-details ajp://localhost:8009/myapp/busy-details/ retry=0 timeout=385

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/myapp/order/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^OrderID=([0-9999999]*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname/myapp/#/orders/edit/%1 [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/myapp/dentist/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DentID=([0-9999999]*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname/myapp/#/dentist/edit/%1 [L,R=301,NE]

</VirtualHost>
```

And tomcat server.xml setting

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="-1" />

 <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
 <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

please see below response we are getting in browser. Here you can see whenever we load our page some part of HTML response is missing this is also happening with normal ajax get request.

In response 1 you can see Response header of one of the HTML page request.

In response 2 you can see we are getting incomplete response with Red dot in chrome network tab.

[Server response 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnwwS.png)

[Server response 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ4kj.png)

Comment: it's really not clear what you are trying to tell us in those screenshots.

Comment: @Claies please see my edited question.